# "Seemingly random numbers" in sobel operator

Tags: computer-vision

I understand that Sobel operator approximate "changes in x-y direction" of an image using three consecutive pixels. But why are these numbers 1 2 1? Where do they come from. I tried to search in Google but none of the results answer my question. Hope you help me clarify this

Comment: Did you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator ? This explains the differential aspect of the operator pretty well. What about the article do you not understand ?